# Como configurar o tempo de inatividade do usuário no Asp.Net Core?

Tags: session, asp.net-core, login, cookies

Comecei a estudar o Asp.Net Core esses dias, estou trabalhando com a versão 2.1.
Já consigo fazer login e logout do usuário, só que não sei como configurar o tempo de inatividade dele.

Coloquei esse código, porém depois de alguns minutos ele pede o login novamente

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.LoginPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/Account/Login");
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
});
```

Comparando com sistemas reais, procuro algo como o Facebook faz, onde você faz o login 1 vez, e se acessar regularmente ele não pede login.

O que devo configurar para fazer isso?

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Identity? qual versão do .net core?

Comment: Versão 2.1 `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>`

Comment: Sim, estou usando Identity com minhas classes customizadas, pois uso um banco já existente

Answer (score 1):

Olá, para o refresh funcionar você precisa definir outra configuração dentro do options chamada **SlidingExpiration** para **true**.

Agora para garantir que estas configurações não sejam sobrescritas você precisará colocar o seu código depois da declaração do **AddIdentity**.